# Contentresolver.delete() not working android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-contentresolver

In my android application i want to remove song from playlist when user longpress particular song. For that i used `Contentresolver.delete()` method but its not working. Neither it throws error nor it remove data ? Here i am posting my code . Please tell me why its not working.

Code :

```
    ContentResolver resolver = DefaultSongList.this.getContentResolver();
    Uri mUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",playListId);  
    String audioId = songsList.get(pos).get("id");
    resolver.delete(mUri,MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID +" = "+ audioId , null);
    Toast.makeText(DefaultSongList.this, "Song removed from Playlist.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Did you check the result of `resolver.delete(...)`?

Comment: Now this code is working for me...there was a little mistake in fetching audioID.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void removePlaylistMember(Context context, long memberid,
        long mplaylistid) {
    try {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
                "external", mplaylistid);
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID
                + "=?";
        String selectionargs[] = { String.valueOf(memberid) };
        context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, selection, selectionargs);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```